# Deserialize Protobuf in python from class name

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

How can I deserialize a protocol buffer message, knowing only the string name of the protoc-generated class?

For some reason, the fully qualified name of the message that I get with `DESCRIPTOR.full_name` does not match the actual location of the python class, so I am unable to deserialize it with the following function:

```
def get_class( kls ):
    """Get class given a fully qualified name of a class"""
    parts = kls.split('.')
    module = ".".join(parts[:-1])
    m = __import__( module )
    for comp in parts[1:]:
        m = getattr(m, comp)
    return m
```

I just get `ImportError` no module (name).

Any help appreciated.

P.S.: In case it helps, the bigger problem I am trying to solve is to serialize the protobuf message to the database, and then deserialize it back out (I am using postgresql with sqlalchemy in this case). Since regular python pickle doesn't work - I am hoping to store a tuple `(message_cls_name, message_binary)` where `message_cls_name` is a fully qualified name of the protobuf message, and `message_binary` is a result of called `SerializeToString` on the message. The part I am not clear about is how to get the message out and deserialize it into proper protobuf class.

Comment: I posted an answer.. hope it helps.. otherwise ask ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example solution..

```
from ocmg_common.protobuf.rpc_pb2 import Exception as PBException
from importlib import import_module

pb_message = PBException(message='hello world')
pb_message_string = pb_message.SerializeToString()

def deserialize(message, typ):
    module_, class_ = typ.rsplit('.', 1)
    class_ = getattr(import_module(module_), class_)
    rv = class_()
    rv.ParseFromString(message)
    return rv

print(deserialize(pb_message_string, 'ocmg_common.protobuf.rpc_pb2.Exception'))
```

will output

```
(env)➜ httppost git:(master) ✗ python test.py
message: "hello world"
```

If you dont know the module, but only have the `DESCRIPTOR.full_name` you have to name them the same way, or create a function that maps a full descriptor name to a module. Otherwise you are stuck and dont know from where to import the module.

I hope it will help you.. ;)
Best of luck..

Comment: Wow, thanks. So is there any way to get the full name `ocmg_common.protobuf.rpc_pb2.Exception` from the actual class `Exception`? Or are you saying that protoc compiler completely disregards where the actual `pb2.py` files are?

Comment: To my understanding you can not get the module name from the class itself, only the `DESCRIPTOR.full_name` which is an internal protobuf name, and thus useless in regard to importing the correct module.

Comment: Or you can use: `pb_message = PBException(); 
pb_message.ParseFromString(pb_message_string); 
print(pb_message)`

Comment: where do you got the module ocmg_common from? I get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ocmg_common'`.

Comment: @Blind0ne, it is my internal Protos, I just used them as an example. You have to use your own protos instead.

Comment: @brunsgaard:- Even i also getting error:- `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ocmg_common'`. Can you give example or share that file..?